# missing icon in the top bar in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, icons

I have removed the icon and I want it back. I can't get it. I've tried to reinstall it, but it did not help.

I have no ownclient command. I do not know how to solve it, I've tried:

```
apt-get purge owncloud-client
apt-get install owncloud-client
```

But this did not help. Package info

dpkg -s owncloud-client

```
   Package: owncloud-client
   Status: install ok installed
   Priority: optional
   Section: devel
   Installed-Size: 47
   Maintainer: Jürgen Weigert jw@owncloud.com
   Architecture: amd64
   Multi-Arch: same
   Version: 2.0.2-1
```

`apt-cache policy owncloud-client`

```
owncloud-client:
  Installed: 2.0.2-1 
  Candidate: 2.0.2-3 
  Version table:
 2.0.2-3 0 
  500 download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/… Packages 
 *** 2.0.2-1 0 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 1.5.0+dfsg-4ubuntu1 0 
  500 de2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy owncloud-client`

Comment: And the output of `find /usr/share/icons/hicolor/ -name '*ownCloud*'`

Comment: $ apt-cache policy owncloud-client
    owncloud-client:Installed: 2.0.2-1
  Candidate: 2.0.2-3
  Version table:
     2.0.2-3 0
        500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/xUbuntu_14.04/  Packages
 *** 2.0.2-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.5.0+dfsg-4ubuntu1 0
        500 http://de2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: find /usr/share/icons/hicolor/ -name '*ownCloud*'and no output

Comment: Upgrade your system: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` run the command `find /usr/share/icons/hicolor/ -name '*ownCloud*'` again.

Comment: I had to use :

        `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`

Comment: You have installed a new kernel to become an icon back?!

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with owncloud-client package.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
should fix this

More info:
https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/4041

Comment: I had to make first remove, after that autoremove and than it installs a newer version 2.0.2-3